# Parsing error in ReactJS but not in vanilla JS

Tags: reactjs

I have a JS file which basically looks like:

```
"use strict";function _typeof(t) ...;

"use strict";function _typeof(t) ...;
```

This code works in vanilla JS + HTML, but when I try to use this in a ReactJS `Identifier '_typeof' has already been declared`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: What do you mean by using it in React.js. Do you write that in a module or you just import react as a <script/> in an html?

Comment: I'm currently importing it in my React component.

Comment: I wrote the solution in an answer in case someone else needs it